# Rails v1.2.3, ActionWebService and .NET platform as client

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, web-services

I'm using Rails 1.2.3 on a project. ( Upgrading rails is not an option ).
I've created a simple test web-service using Rails. I've tested using the Rails invoke scaffold. It seems to generate the response with no problems.

I'm trying to setup a client via .NET. I've created an ASP.NET Web App project in C#. I am adding a "Web Reference", add the Reference URL into the URL field of the wizard,

```
http://mydomain.com:3000/backend/api
```

then I receive an error from the wizard:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://mydomain.com:3000/backend/api'
>   The request failed with the error
>   message:
>
> GET not supported
>
> There was an error downloading
>   'http://mydomain.com:3000/backend/api/$metadata'
>   The request failed with the error
>   message:
>
> GET not supported

My code is:

```
# in app/apis/address_api.rb
class AddressApi < ActionWebService::API::Base
   api_method   :gettest, :returns => [:string]
end

# in app/controllers/backend_controller
class BackendController < ApplicationController
  wsdl_service_name 'Backend'
  web_service_api AddressApi
  web_service_scaffold :invoke

  def gettest
    return "hello"
  end

end
```

Are there any known issues between ActionWebService and .NET or am I doing something wrong? Is my URL correct for a rails web-service?

Answer (score 0):

This has probably been answered elsewhere, but since this question pops up when searching google for actionwebservice and get requests, I thought I would answer it here.

By default AWS refuses non-POST requests. Specifically it has code in action_controller_dispatcher.rb that reads:

```
def dispatch_web_service_request
  if request.get?
    render_text('GET not supported', '500 GET not supported')
    return
  end
  ..
```

Basically you have to either set up the request to POST the request instead of GETting it. Or you have to override AWS's handling of GET requests. (You might try editing the code inside the gem, but (1) that will get overwritten when you update the gem and (2) I'm not sure how good an idea that is in general and (3) I've never tried it.

The former is likely more appropriate if you have control of the code generating the request. If you don't, Zack Chandler had a workaround (for QuickBooks's connection to a web-service, but it should work in any case), [here](http://www.depixelate.com/2006/12/13/rails-and-quickbooks-integration-part-3/).

I'm quoting it below in case the url changes.

> Create a patch file in lib/action_web_service_ext.rb
>
> ```
> module ActionController
>   class Base
>
>     alias_method :old_dispatch_web_service_request, :dispatch_web_service_request
>
>     # --- [ QBWC requests the api url with a GET request upon loading the QWC file for the first time ] ---
>     def dispatch_web_service_request
>       render :nothing => true and return if request.get?
>       old_dispatch_web_service_request
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Enable the patch in config/environment.rb
>
> ```
> require 'action_web_service_ext.rb'
> ```

Obviously the code inside the dispatch_web_service_request method is QuickBooks specific, but you should get the idea.

Hope this helps, and I hope Zack doesn't mind me reposting.